# WhatsappAPI - How to know if can send any message or just template messages

Tags: php, whatsapp

Here's the deal:

In WhatsApp cloud API if you are initiating the conversation with the user, you can only send template messages.
The problem is if I try to send other types of messages (image or pure text for example) the API does not send me any error, it just sends a success message, but the message is not really delivered to the user.
How can I tell if am can send other messages?

I'm using PHP to send messages with cURL, but I don't know if this is relevant.
Anyway, here's the code:

Just for clarification, this code is already working, I just want to know what I need to do to get an error  when I cannot send text messages

```php
class ApiWhatsapp
{
    private $TOKEN = "";
    private $VERSION = "";
    private $PHONE_NUMBER_ID = "";
    private $BUSINESS_ACCOUNT = "";

    function __construct() {
        global $conectado;
        $select = "SELECT FIRST 1 * FROM IDSWHATS";
        $arrayIds = $conectado->select($select);
        foreach ($arrayIds as $ids) {
            $this->TOKEN =$ids->TOKEN;
            $this->VERSION =$ids->VERSION;
            $this->PHONE_NUMBER_ID =$ids->PHONE_NUMBER_ID;
            $this->BUSINESS_ACCOUNT =$ids->BUSINESS_ACCOUNT;
        }

        if (!$this->TOKEN) {
            throw new Exception("credentials not found");
        }

    }

    function sendMessageText($to, $text) {
        
        $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$this->VERSION.'/'.$this->PHONE_NUMBER_ID.'/messages';
        $data = [
            "messaging_product" => "whatsapp",
            "recipient_type" => "individual",
            "to" => $to,
            "type" => "text",
            "text" => [
                "preview_url" => false,
                "body" => $text
            ]
        ];

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $headers = array(
            "Accept: application/json",
            "Content-Type: application/json",
            "Authorization: Bearer " . $this->TOKEN
        );
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
        $resp = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return json_decode($resp);
    }
}
```

the success response I get:

```json
{
    "status": "success",
    "message_id": "wamid.HBgMNTUzMTczNTgxNDUzFQIAERgSRjM3RDYzMUUyMkY2Rjk5OTJEAA==",
    "response_array": {
        "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
        "contacts": [
            {
                "input": "5531973581453",
                "wa_id": "553173581453"
            }
        ],
        "messages": [
            {
                "id": "wamid.HBgMNTUzMTczNTgxNDUzFQIAERgSRjM3RDYzMUUyMkY2Rjk5OTJEAA=="
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a rule in [WhatsApp Business API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/get-started#sent-test-message),

> Message templates are the only type of message that can be sent to customers who have yet to message you, or have not messaged you in the last 24 hours. Thus, message templates are primarily used to initiate conversations with customers.

It means the business can send other types of messages only if the user replies to the business in 24 hours window.

Second, WhatsApp will forward this kind of error in webhook only, so send message API response with success but to check the real state of the message you need to [set up webhook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/guides/set-up-webhooks).

---

If you really wanted to check if the user replied in 24 hours then I would suggest you a way to handle this kind of situation,

- first of all, you need to setup webhook because you will receive user's messages in webhook
- when you receive a message from a user in webhook, you need to store *(in the database)* that user's contact no with the date
- while sending a message check that the phone number in your database, is contact no has been replied to in 24 hours then you can send other types of messages otherwise send a template-type message

Comment: I didn't knew that I would receive the errors on webhook! thank you for this information. Alson, you're right, i'll need to save the time if I want to have total control over this