# Send audio Whatsapp API, it returns success but the audio does not arrive on the phone

Tags: whatsapp, whatsapi, whatsapp-cloud-api

I'm trying to send an audio to the whatsapp API, below the code and the return, it returns success but the audio does not arrive on the cell phone

SEND MEDIA

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/xxxxxxxxxx/media \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer EAAD....' \
  --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  --form file=@/Users/2_1687628467.mp3 \
  --form type=audio/mp3 \
  --form messaging_product=whatsapp
```

RETURN

```
{
    "id": "969850597766683"
}
```

SEND MESSAGE

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/xxxxxxxxxx/messages \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer EAAD...' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp", 
  "recipient_type": "individual",
  "to": "MY_PHONE_NUMBER",
  "type": "audio",
  "audio": {
      "id": "969850597766683"
  }
}'
```

RETURN SEND MESSAGE

```
{
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "contacts": [
        {
            "input": "MY_PHONE_NUMBER",
            "wa_id": "MY_PHONE_NUMBER"
        }
    ],
    "messages": [
        {
            "id": "wamid.HBgMNTU2NTkyNjY1MDYwFQI=="
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You have to setup a webhook to track your issue, make sure you are aware of the rule that businesses can initiate a conversation by template-type messages only if the user replies then you can send other types of messages (media, text, etc) in 24 hours window. read more [here in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75856649/8987128).

Comment: The Webhook affected me error, the format it was sending and incompatible

RETUN
Audio file uploaded with mimetype as audio\/ogg; codecs=opus, however on processing it is of type application\/octet-stream. Please choose a different file.

"errors":[
       {
          "code":131053,
          "title":"Media upload error",
          "message":"Media upload error",
          "error_data":{
             "details":"Audio file uploaded with mimetype as audio\/ogg; codecs=opus, however on processing it is of type application\/octet-stream. Please choose a different file."
          }

Answer (score 0):

review the mime type you created the audio with, it should be audio/mpeg